# How to extract FSAs from postal codes when there is no match?

Tags: r, text-mining, information-extraction

I would like to extract Canadian FSAs from unstrucured data. I want to pull only the first instance of each match.

The problem: Some data don't include postal code and my function won't produce the replacement columns because the match list isn't as long as the original data.

How can I produce a "stand in" value so my replacement column is the same length?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

addresse <- c("H3C0C6, Canada",                           
              "H3C0C6, Canada",                           
              "Rue Riviera, Montréal, QC H8Z 3H7, Canada",
              "H9E1G2, Canada",                           
              "H9E1G2, Canada",
              "1288 Rue Saint-Antoine O, Montréal, QC")

df <- data.frame(addresse)

#pattern for QC postal FSA
pattern <- "H\\d{1}\\w?"

#row 6 is returning character(0)
df$FSA <- regmatches(df[,1],
           regexpr(pattern, df[,1], perl=T))

View(df)

#trying to get rid of character(0)
x<-character(0)
df$FSA <- if(isTRUE(identical(x,regmatches(df[,1],
                                regexpr(pattern, df[,1], perl=T))))){"NA"
                                }else{
                                    regmatches(df[,1],
                                         regexpr(pattern, df[,1], perl=T))}
```

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kjetil b halvorsen mentioned, this question migh be off-topf here and. It might fit better to stackoverflow.

Since you added a reproducible example, I will quickly try to give a solution:

You could use `mutate` combined with `str_extract`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# generate some data
addresse <- c("H3C0C6, Canada",                           
              "H3C0C6, Canada",                           
              "Rue Riviera, Montréal, QC H8Z 3H7, Canada",
              "H9E1G2, Canada",                           
              "H9E1G2, Canada",
              "1288 Rue Saint-Antoine O, Montréal, QC")

df <- data.frame(addresse)

# pattern for QC postal FSA
pattern <- "H\\d{1}\\w?"

# extract first match
df %>%
  group_by(addresse) %>% 
  mutate(match=str_extract(addresse,pattern)) #generates NA if no match
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#> # Groups:   addresse [4]
#>   addresse                                  match
#>   <chr>                                     <chr>
#> 1 H3C0C6, Canada                            H3C  
#> 2 H3C0C6, Canada                            H3C  
#> 3 Rue Riviera, Montréal, QC H8Z 3H7, Canada H8Z  
#> 4 H9E1G2, Canada                            H9E  
#> 5 H9E1G2, Canada                            H9E  
#> 6 1288 Rue Saint-Antoine O, Montréal, QC    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks this worked! I'll use stackoverflow in future